# Why am I able to use System.Collections.Generic namespace without having a reference to any assembly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I removed all references from the *References* node but I am still able to use `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. Why? Is it because Visual Studio somehow adds them by default? But if that is the case, I should be able to see it my *.csproj* file at least.

What's going on here?

[image]

Comment: There's no `System.Collections.Generic.dll`. That namespace is in "mscorlib.dll".

Comment: @Enigmativity That is not what I meant that I do not have reference to `System.Collections.Generic.dll` but I meant I do not have any references.

Comment: You get "mscorlib.dll" for free.

Comment: @enigmativity And you get a +1 on your comment. Sadly all I can offer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The documentation for `List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) says the class is defined in `mscorlib`. This is automatically implicitly available to every C# project out there. It has to be, because it's the same assembly which defines basic types such as `object`, `void`, `string`, `int`. You're not going to be able to write C# code without those, that's why the assembly is given special treatment.

There are ways to suppress its inclusion, but that's only useful if you intend to re-implement the whole .NET runtime, you won't be able to use the resulting assembly otherwise.

Comment: Where does it mention they are implicitly referenced?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx: "All desktop projects contain an implicit reference to mscorlib."

Comment: Great! I really appreciate the link. i had no idea about the implicit reference. The odd part is when I go into add references, mscorlib.dll is not even checked.

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces don't necessarily map one-to-one with assemblies. There doesn't have to be a separate `System.Collections.Generic.dll` or `System.Collections.Specialized.dll`, for example.

The `mscorlib.dll` and `System.dll` assemblies contain most of the "basic" namespaces, and they're implicitly referenced in your C# project.

Comment: Yes I understand and am aware that it is not a 1:1 map. Where does it mention they are implicitly referenced?