# What is the reason after I open an old ASP.NET project to find fault "Server Error in '/' Application."

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

After launching on ASP.NET PRIVATE API I see error like this:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'Dictionary<,>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Source Error:


Line 4:  @{
Line 5:      // Group the samples into a single tab if they are the same.
Line 6:      Dictionary<string, object> samples = Model.GroupBy(pair => pair.Value).ToDictionary(
Line 7:          pair => String.Join(", ", pair.Select(m => m.Key.ToString()).ToArray()), 
Line 8:          pair => pair.Key);
```

I have no errors in the project, but I cannot understand why I cannot start the project.

My web.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Private_API" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone give me the exact instructions how to fix the problem  step by step ?

Comment: The message "You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Collections" seem to be the most relevant bit of the error. It seems you have a reference and/or DLL file missing from the project settings / bin folder. Check that you've got all the correct packages and references loaded before building/running the application.

Comment: How can I check that I have too many .dll files..
How can I find who is missing ?

Comment: it would be the one with the name mentioned in the error message. Or, in your Visual Studio project, check the project References.

Comment: I cannot find a solution for this problem..

Comment: Ok but that doesn't tell me anything about what you've tried, or what your project contains, or what you looked for and found / didn't find. Just telling me you can't do it doesn't allow me to help you further. Did you understand what I mean about checking the project references?

Comment: https://github.com/Zombayo123/Private-API-git
This is a project

Comment: Ok. I can't check and run it for you, but from a brief glance at the csproj file it seems like your project does not contain a reference to System.Collections. So you need to add one. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019

Comment: Or it's possible you are somehow missing some core libraries where this namespace might be contained. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47120050/5947043. Also make sure your project is targeting the correct .NET version, make sure you do a Clean and then Build before attempting to run it again. If you still problems, restart Visual Studio. Maybe restart your computer. And if necessary, in extremis, just create a brand new VS Project and copy your code files into it.